# CSS Flex items not filling container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Struggling to get the flex items inside the calculator to fill the parent.
Have been messing with so many declarations i'm going crazy.

Thought it was maybe because I didnt have flex-wrap set properly.. however that didn't seem to fix the issue.
Any advice on where to start looking on that to make the buttons fill the calculator content?
Also saw the bottom row is off by a tiny bit and not centred, however this has been set to centre already?

Many thanks,

```css
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #d2a5a5;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

button {
    background-color: #d2a5a5;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.calculator {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 6px solid rgb(1, 1, 1);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 5px;
}

    .display {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .display input {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000;
    }

    .calculator .content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: stretch;
        align-items: stretch;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .calculator .row {
        display: flex;
    }

        .calculator .row .button {
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color:rgb(1, 1, 1);
        }

        .calculator .row .button.zero {
            flex: 2;
        }

            .calculator .row .button:hover {
                background-color: #ccc;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="calculator">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="screen">
                    <input type="text" class="display" value="0" disabled />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(7)">
                        7
                    </button>
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(8)">
                        8
                    </button>
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(9)">
                        9
                    </button>
                    <button
                        class="button"
                        onclick="calculator.addOperator('/')"
                    >
                        /
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(7)">
                        7
                    </button>
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(8)">
                        8
                    </button>
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(9)">
                        9
                    </button>
                    <button
                        class="button"
                        onclick="calculator.addOperator('*')"
                    >
                        *
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(4)">
                        4
                    </button>
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(5)">
                        5
                    </button>
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(6)">
                        6
                    </button>
                    <button
                        class="button"
                        onclick="calculator.addOperator('-')"
                    >
                        -
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(1)">
                        1
                    </button>
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(2)">
                        2
                    </button>
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(3)">
                        3
                    </button>
                    <button
                        class="button"
                        onclick="calculator.addOperator('+')"
                    >
                        +
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <button
                        class="button zero"
                        onclick="calculator.addDigit(0)"
                    >
                        0
                    </button>
                    <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDecimal()">
                        .
                    </button>
                    <button
                        class="button"
                        onclick="calculator.addOperator('=')"
                    >
                        =
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.
I just added `width: 100% and height: 100%`, and set height `20%` to `.screen` class element relative to `.calculator` class element. and, added `box-sizing: border-box` as universal style.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #d2a5a5;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

button {
  background-color: #d2a5a5;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.calculator {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 6px solid rgb(1, 1, 1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

.display {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.display input {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

.calculator .content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content .screen {
  height: 20%;
}

.content .screen input {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

.calculator .row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.calculator .row .button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
}

.calculator .row .button.zero {
  flex: 2;
}

.calculator .row .button:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="screen">
        <input type="text" class="display" value="0" disabled />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(7)">
                        7
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(8)">
                        8
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(9)">
                        9
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addOperator('/')">
                        /
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(7)">
                        7
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(8)">
                        8
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(9)">
                        9
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addOperator('*')">
                        *
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(4)">
                        4
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(5)">
                        5
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(6)">
                        6
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addOperator('-')">
                        -
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(1)">
                        1
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(2)">
                        2
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDigit(3)">
                        3
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addOperator('+')">
                        +
                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="button zero" onclick="calculator.addDigit(0)">
                        0
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addDecimal()">
                        .
                    </button>
        <button class="button" onclick="calculator.addOperator('=')">
                        =
                    </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey Sachin, thanks for the assist! Perfect. Easy fix when you think about it.. but it turns to a blur after trying things over and over haha.

Comment: Happy to help you :)